# Adding brackets to e-mail address field with sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed

How to sandwich only an e-mail address field with brackets in my address book? My address book consists of name, surname, nickname, mailing address (a csv format). I must add brackets only to the addresses to comfort with the format of address book of my new mailer (MUA). I would like to know how to implement this with sed/awk.
The MWE is as follows:

`John,Doe,JohnDoe,john_doe@gmail.com`

The converted result is desired to be like this:

`JohnDoe John Doe <john_doe@gmail.com>`

Should I depend on the fact that only addresses include the at-mark? In this case, if the other fields include this mark, errors might occur resultingly. Thanks in advance for your advises.

Comment: Why don't you add an example line from your csv file to your question so we know what you have?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I added MWE.

Comment: Do you have any attempt to share with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your addition of .csv content of:

```
John,Doe,JohnDoe,john_doe@gmail.com
```

Where you need to enclose the `"john_doe@fmail.com"` within `<...>`, you can simply do:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$4="<"$4">"}1' file
```

Which will then modify each record in the file adding `"<"` and `">"` at the end of the 4th field before using the default print command shorthand `1` at the end to output the record. Setting the variable `OFS` (Output Field Separator)  to `','` ensures each output field is separated by a comma.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "John,Doe,JohnDoe,john_doe@gmail.com" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$4="<"$4">"}1'
John,Doe,JohnDoe,<john_doe@gmail.com>
```

**Output Without `','` Separators**

Since you also show wanted output without any .csv comma separators, you can simply not alter `OFS` and that will produce space-separated output, e.g.

```
$ echo "John,Doe,JohnDoe,john_doe@gmail.com" | awk -F, '{$4="<"$4">"}1'
John Doe JohnDoe <john_doe@gmail.com>
```

**Rearranging Field Order To Match Your Wanted Output**

As [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) caught, you are swapping the first couple of fields as well. To accomplish the field reorder and cap the e-mail address, you can do:

```
awk -F, '{print $3, $1, $2, "<"$4">"}' file
```

**Example Rearranged**

```
$ echo "John,Doe,JohnDoe,john_doe@gmail.com" | awk -F, '{print $3, $1, $2, "<"$4">"}'
JohnDoe John Doe <john_doe@gmail.com>
```

There are several way to approach this issue, but using `awk` with this, or something similar, is likely to be among the most efficient.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Looks like the OP wants to rearrange the fields too: `awk -F, '{print $3, $1, $2, "<"$4">"}' file`.

Comment: @EdMorton - you are hitting on all 8 this morning. Thank you. Slipped right by me.